# Inline English grammar checker for vim-latex?

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, filetype-tex, grammar-checking

I am looking for English grammar checker for vim-latex suite that checks the grammar as I type but does not highlight what's inside `$$` or `\begin{equation}` & `\end{equation}` commands. Is there any such a thing?

I know that there is a LanguageTool but it seems that it does not work with `.tex` file.

Comment: Can you post a simple example document which doesn't work well with TeX? Adding a basic equation doesn't seem to give any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ultimate solution.
[vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) with language tools using [YaLafi](https://github.com/matze-dd/YaLafi) .
See the `vim` section of Yalafi's github page!!

Unlike above solution, you can also perform grammar check using `LanguageTools`, which is the solution which I wanted in the first place.

It rips the equations and characters from the current tex file and performs spell and grammar check using standalone language tools.
You can even set your own replacing rules such that non-trivial names or sets of text can be replaced to common names like "John" or "Law" so that Language tools won't get confused with field-specific terms that aren't supported.

Comment: More detail would certainly improve this answer

Comment: What kind of detail you want?? Everything is written on YaLafi's documentation. I'm not a developer of YaLafi, so I can't add anything more useful to this answer.

Comment: Well, we generally like answers to be self-contained with links as support. That means the main content of the answer should be, well, in the answer. So mentioning what YaLafi is might be good. Also on a separate note, you could explain how to use vimtex with YaLafi (you don't have to cover installation unless there are tricky steps, but it would be nice to cover keybindings/commands/whatever you need to know to use it regularly).

Answer (score 2):

[vim-latexsuite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) is a very good addition for writing LaTeX documents and will handle spell checking as you want it to. Meaning, ignore equasions in spell checking and it also does a lot of other great stuff.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already knew that and I already have that.